# Generate permanent access token Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the [graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and I am generating the access token using the right navigation panel with `read_attribution` credentials.

[image]

The issue I am facing is the token I am generating is not permanent. How can I get a permanent token?

Comment: Outside of business manager context, there is no such thing as a permanent user token. But you can extend a short-lived user token to be valid for up to 60 days, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am building the back-end of a permanent dashboard for a company A using the `attribution_API`. In that case, I will have to update the application (at least change the token manually) 6 times per year?

Comment: in general, you should always implement something to check if the token is still valid - because a token also gets invalidated if the user who created it changes his password afaik. no matter if it is a user or page token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact Facebook in order to get permanant tokens